# Keep rows in df1 based on indices in in df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames like this:

**df_1**

| index | index_col | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 4.4 |
| 1 | 7 | 5.6 |
| 2 | 12 | 8.2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

**df_2**

| index | values |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.4 |
| 1 | 12.6 |
| 2 | 64.6 |
| ... | ... |

I want to keep all the rows in `df_2` based on the indices in `index_col` from `df_1`. How do I do this in an efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df3 = df2[df2.index.isin(df1['index_col'])]
```

Or [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df3 = (df2.merge(df1[['index_col']], left_index=True, right_on='index_col')
          .drop('index_col', axis=1))
```